# How to store combined arrays fetched using Apollo Client?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo Client with Next.js and I'm fetching two types of data with a single query: Properties and Adverts. E.g.

```
query getPropertiesAndAdverts() {
    search() {
        _id
        ref
        title
        price
        images {
            url
            description
        }
    }
    adverts {
        advertiser
        campaign
        url
        images {
            url
        }
        startDate
        endDate
    }
}
```

Both of these are arrays of data and once I have the data fetched from the remote source I need to merge the two arrays at a specific frequency (a separate JS function). This will result in a single array of data which is to be used as the content for a page in a Next.js application.

**Once I have combined the two arrays, how is it best to handle that combined array of data?** Should I store it in React state, use [Apollo Reactive Variables](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/reactive-variables/), [write to Apollo cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/), or alternative?

To provide a little extra info on the usage:

- This combined data will be passed to a couple of other components which need to re-render when the content changes.
- I need data to be fetched automatically on initial page load, after that it will be triggered based on user interaction (interacting with a search form and clicking Submit, or use pagination controls to page through the data)
- Every time a user submits a new search I need to make sure I fetch the remote data according to the search criteria they’ve entered so this will alter the Post data that is returned and a new combined array needs to be created accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest merging the two arrays using [useMemo](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) and then making that computation dependent on the appropriate variables. The result of the `useMemo` function is *essentially* a state variable that you can pass to other components.

You shouldn't need to cache the combined array in the apollo-client cache as each result will already be cached.